# Combine duplicates in Excel based on values from 2 columns, produce the sum and and % from others, remove dups

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have been struggling with my Excel report trying to roll up duplicate rows based on 2 column values. Also need to calculate the sum of the 3rd and 4th column and calculate the percentage.

Here is the data

```
a1      b1          c1  d1  e1
disc1   song1234    3   20  15%
disc2   song78      2   30  7%
disc1   song54      1   10  10%
disc3   song4       4   10  40%
disc4   song0       1   15  7%
disc2   song78      2   16  13%
disc1   song1234    0   19  0%
disc4   song9       1   20  5%
disc1   song1234    0   10  0%
```

here is what I've tried so far:

```
Public Sub duplicateRollUp()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False      '
Dim SUMcols()                           '### declare a second empty array for our sum columns
Dim AVtemp()                            '### declare a third empty array for our temp values we need to calculate %
SUMcols() = Array(3, 4)          '### the second array stores the columns which should be summed up
Sheets("test").Select

   Dim LLoop As Integer
   Dim LTestLoop As Integer
   Dim LClearRange As String
   Dim Lrows As Integer
   Dim LRange As String

   'Column A values
   Dim LChangedValue As String
   Dim LTestValue As String

   'Column B values
   Dim LChangedValueB As String
   Dim LTestValueB As String

   'Test first 1000 rows in spreadsheet for uniqueness
   Lrows = 1000
   LLoop = 2

   'Clear all flags
   LClearRange = "A13:B" & Lrows
   Range(LClearRange).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

   'Check first 1000 rows in spreadsheet
   While LLoop <= Lrows
  LChangedValue = "A" & CStr(LLoop)
  LChangedValueB = "B" & CStr(LLoop)
  If Len(Range(LChangedValue).Value) > 0 Then

     'Test each value for dups
     LTestLoop = 2
     While LTestLoop <= Lrows
        If LLoop <> LTestLoop Then
           LTestValue = "A" & CStr(LTestLoop)
           LTestValueB = "B" & CStr(LTestLoop)
           'Value has been duplicated in another cell
           If (Range(LChangedValue).Value = Range(LTestValue).Value) And (Range(LChangedValueB).Value = Range(LTestValueB).Value) Then
              'Set the background color to yellow in column A
              Range(LChangedValue).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
              Range(LTestValue).Interior.ColorIndex = 6

              'Set the background color to yellow in column B
              Range(LChangedValueB).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
              Range(LTestValueB).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
           End If
        End If

        LTestLoop = LTestLoop + 1
     Wend

  End If

  LLoop = LLoop + 1

   Wend

Application.ScreenUpdating = True       '### re-enable our screen updating
End Sub                                 '### ends our macro
```

Comment: Please show us what vba you've written so far, what it does and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show what you want for results.  But it sounds like you want to produce a table which combines the duplicates in your original list.  I would define a class, and use the collection object to test for duplicates and combine.  The collection object is handy for this as it will return an error if you try to add an object with a pre-existing key.  The Class is handy for a number of reasons, not the least of which is that it makes the code more understandable, as the properties can have meaningful names.  And also, you don't have to keep track of all the different arrays.

Here is the code:  Hopefully it is understandable so you can modify it as needed for your real data.

And, I'm not sure which cells you want to color.  If the one's you want to color are those that are the result of combining duplicates, that logic can be easily added.

**EDIT** After re-reading your code, it appears you want to color the rows that are the results of combining duplicates.  The code below has been modified accordingly.  We add a marker to the class object (IsDup) to keep track of this, and use that when we write the results.

### Class Object

- Rename the class object **cSongs**

---

```
Option Explicit
Private pDisc As String
Private pSong As String
Private pC1_ As Long
Private pD1_ As Long
Private pE1_ As Double
Private pIsDup As Boolean

Public Property Get Disc() As String
    Disc = pDisc
End Property
Public Property Let Disc(Value As String)
    pDisc = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Song() As String
    Song = pSong
End Property
Public Property Let Song(Value As String)
    pSong = Value
End Property

Public Property Get C1_() As Long
    C1_ = pC1_
End Property
Public Property Let C1_(Value As Long)
    pC1_ = Value
End Property

Public Property Get D1_() As Long
    D1_ = pD1_
End Property
Public Property Let D1_(Value As Long)
    pD1_ = Value
End Property

Public Property Get E1_() As Double
    E1_ = Me.C1_ / Me.D1_
End Property

Public Property Get IsDup() As Boolean
    IsDup = pIsDup
End Property
Public Property Let IsDup(Value As Boolean)
    pIsDup = Value
End Property
```

---

### Regular Module

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub GroupDiscSongs()
    Dim cS As cSongs, colS As Collection
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes() As Variant
    Dim I As Long
    Dim sKey As String
    Dim C As Range

'Set Source and Results worksheets and range
Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Range("H1")

'Get Source Data
With wsSrc
    vSrc = .Range("a1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=4)
End With

'Collect Songs data and combine duplicates
Set colS = New Collection
On Error Resume Next 'to test for duplicates
For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc)
    Set cS = New cSongs
    With cS
        .Disc = vSrc(I, 1)
        .Song = vSrc(I, 2)
        .C1_ = vSrc(I, 3)
        .D1_ = vSrc(I, 4)
        .IsDup = False
        sKey = .Disc & "|" & .Song
        colS.Add cS, sKey
        If Err.Number = 457 Then
            Err.Clear
            With colS(sKey)
                .C1_ = .C1_ + cS.C1_
                .D1_ = .D1_ + cS.D1_
                .IsDup = True
            End With
        ElseIf Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
            Stop
        End If
    End With
Next I
On Error GoTo 0

'Results array
ReDim vRes(0 To colS.Count, 1 To 5)

'Header row
    vRes(0, 1) = "a1"
    vRes(0, 2) = "b1"
    vRes(0, 3) = "c1"
    vRes(0, 4) = "d1"
    vRes(0, 5) = "e1"

'Data
For I = 1 To colS.Count
    With colS(I)
        vRes(I, 1) = .Disc
        vRes(I, 2) = .Song
        vRes(I, 3) = .C1_
        vRes(I, 4) = .D1_
        vRes(I, 5) = .E1_
        'add marker for duplicate for conditional formatting
        If .IsDup Then vRes(I, 1) = Chr(2) & vRes(I, 1)
    End With
Next I

'Write the results
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    With .Rows(1)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    .Columns(5).NumberFormat = "0%"
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = .Columns(2).ColumnWidth

'Color rows from dups and remove marker
    Set C = .Columns(1).Find(what:=Chr(2), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
        If Not C Is Nothing Then
            C = Mid(C, 2) 'remove the marker
            .Rows(C.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            Do
                Set C = .Columns(1).FindNext(C)
                If Not C Is Nothing Then
                    C = Mid(C, 2)
                    .Rows(C.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                End If
            Loop Until C Is Nothing
        End If

    .Sort key1:=.Columns(1), order1:=xlAscending, _
                key2:=.Columns(2), order2:=xlAscending, _
                MatchCase:=False, Header:=xlYes
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

---

This is what the results look like, given your sample data:

[image]